# In TornadoFX, how can I select a deeply-nested property on an nullable property of an ItemViewModel?

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

TornadoFX has an `select` function that is used to access a property within a property. For example, the usage would be:

```
textfield(viewModel.customerProperty.select(Customer::nameProperty))
```

And that works fine, however, in case that the `customerProperty`'s value is nullable (`Customer?`), `select` doesn't work, because it expects non-null object to "select" from.

In case that the `Property` has `nullable` value, how can `select` be used on it?

Comment: You don't need to declare the type as nullable even though the property can contain null. I suggest to simply change the type of the property and you should be good.

Comment: That worked! Can you post this as an answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: Great! I've added an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare the type as nullable even though the property can contain null. Simply change the type of the property and you should be good.